# GWT Timer lifecycle

Tags: java, gwt, timer

Let's say I have the following ([ref page](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html)):

```
public class TimerExample implements EntryPoint, ClickHandler {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    Button b = new Button("Click and wait 5 seconds");
    b.addClickHandler(this);

    RootPanel.get().add(b);
  }

  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // Create a new timer that calls Window.alert().
    Timer t = new Timer() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Window.alert("Nifty, eh?");
      }
    };

    // Schedule the timer to run once in 5 seconds.
    t.schedule(5000);
  }
}
```

How come the Timer is still around after the method `onClick` exits?  Shouldn't the automatic local variables be garbage collected?

Does this have to do with the fact we are talking about a HTML timer and thus the object exists outside of the automatic local variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Timer.schedule(int delayMillis)` method adds itself (the instance of Timer) to a List of Timers (source code from 2.5.0-rc1):

```
  /**
   * Schedules a timer to elapse in the future.
   * 
   * @param delayMillis how long to wait before the timer elapses, in
   *          milliseconds
   */
  public void schedule(int delayMillis) {
    if (delayMillis < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("must be non-negative");
    }
    cancel();
    isRepeating = false;
    timerId = createTimeout(this, delayMillis);
    timers.add(this);  // <-- Adds itself to a static ArrayList<Timer> here
  }
```

---

From comment by @veer explaining the scheduler thread:

> The timer is going to be handled by a scheduler thread that holds a
>   reference to the Timer and thus *righfully* prevents it from being
>   garbage collected.

Comment: Right. The timer is going to be handled by a scheduler thread that holds a reference to the `Timer` and thus *righfully* prevents it from being garbage collected.

Comment: @veer good elaboration, I've put that at the bottom if that's okay with you.

Comment: Note to self:  check source-code before posting.  Thanks edwardsmatt